# Not getting the satisfactory output. why?

Tags: java, operators

Im new to java.. and after writing a code im getting a solution which was unexpected from my side. Please guide me why my output isnt 5 , 5 ?

I had written a code -

```
import java.util.*;
public class hwlec3 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    int x = 2;
    int y = 5;
    int exp1 = (x * y / x);
    int exp2 = (x * (y / x));

    System.out.print(exp1 + " , ");
    System.out.print(exp2);
    }
}
```

I was expecting an output -
5,5
But i got an output -
5,4

Comment: Because [order of operations](https://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-pemdas.html). In `exp1`, 2 * 5 is 10, and 10 / 2 is 5. In `exp2`, 5 / 2 is 2 (remainder is ignored), and 2 * 2 is 4.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto what the other person said, integer does not account for remainder so (y/x) results in 2 instead of 2.5. The .5 is gone, since the variable is declared as an integer. Thus 2*2 = 4. You could fix this by using double instead of integer.